# Is there a single-line way of initializing a string?

Tags: c, string, char

Is there a single-line way to initialize a string? For example, in C# you would simply do:

`string str = "Example";`

In **C** I would like to do something like the following, but my compiler complains:

`char str[] = "Example";`

EDIT:

`char str[] = "Example";`

...DOES in fact work. My compiler was complaining about this line, but the real issue was something on the previous line. Daniel Fischer's comment below is what lead to this discovery. Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: `char str[] = "Example";` is perfectly valid C, and one of the recommended ways.

Comment: The C snippet is legal. Please post the compiler error.

Comment: C2500 (E) Illegal token "char". C2225 (E) Undeclared name "str". C2500 (E) Illegal token "]".

Comment: Please post a small program the exhibits the problem.

Comment: Forgot a semicolon on the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method of initializing a string is already correct. You probably have the errors somewhere else above that line.

Technically, there're two ways to do this:

```
char str1[] = "string";  // static array 
char* str2 = "string";   // Pointer points to a constant
```

Static array ( 1<sup>st</sup> method ) is recommended here because you can modify the content after you initialize it. However, you can't modify the content of the 2<sup>nd</sup> method because the string will be stored in read-only memory.

NOTE: For the 2<sup>nd</sup> method, alternatively, you can allocate a new memory for the new string instead of modifying the current string. After you allocate it, use `strcpy()` function to assign the string. Also, don't forget to call `free(str);` to dereallocate the memory when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one among these two ways...

1. use string as collection of characters terminates by null ( '\0' ) character.

   char ch[] = {'E','x','a','m','p','l','e','\0'};
2. if you want that, like array incrementing or decrementing array variable name should produce an ERROR then you can also use.

   const char *ch = "Example";

Comment: Your second approach is wrong. There **should** be the `const` qualifier. Really.

Comment: Still not good, suffers from multiple problems. Please read up about `const`.